# Is Using Psycopg2 with Django Ok?

Tags: django, psycopg2

I prefer using Psycopg2 over Django's built-in database handling system. Are there any major disadvantages to this? Would this not work well with larger-scale projects? Are there any important features that I would be missing out on this way?

Comment: Django (can) use(s) Psycopg(2) under the hood. You can always execute direct SQL queries from Django. You'd be missing out on all the Django ORM features, so if you only use Psycopg directly, there is hardly a reason to use Django.

Comment: But it's unclear why you want to use Psycopg over Django. What advantages do you see for your usecase? Please make your question about one (or a few) very practical points; this is a very generic, open question, which is hard (if not impossible) to properly answer.

Comment: As to the question posed in (only) the title: the answer to that is **yes**.

Comment: I'm just more familiar with SQL than the Django database system. Could you please elaborate on what features I'd be missing out on? Thank you

Comment: Also, consider using Psycopg, which is more recent (yes!) than Psycopg2.

Comment: Why do you want to use Django then? Do you know about ORM?

Comment: I have a very basic understanding of ORM

Comment: Have you read through the documentation, like the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial02/) and the [database overview](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/)?

Comment: Not entirely, I'm quite new to Django...

Comment: Time to learn and try out then. That's the best way to find the answer to your question, in particular whether it's suitable for you.

Comment: @9769953, `pyscopg2` and `psycopg(3)` are both actively maintained and recent. They differ in how they interact with the database per [psycopg(3) vs psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/from_pg2.html).

Comment: Personally I got tired with fighting the ORM  and new work I do is with Flask(substitute micro framework of you choice)  using `psycopg2/psycopg` directly. With the [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/sql.html) module and [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses) or [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) you can achieve what you want fairly easily  without the overhead.